# Drupal 7 how to programmatically display resent comment from all article with author image and comment content?

Tags: 7, theming, comments

I'm just use built in function `comment_get_recent($number);` but its only fetch resent comment's subject and author name, is any built in function available which display resent comment with author image comment subject and comment content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[comment_load($cid)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_load/7) should load the entire comment object based on the comment id ($cid).

What you do with it then is up to you.